# pywinauto, manipulate windows with variable titles

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am trying to write an automation script that involves interacting with windows that have titles that change based on the user-set search parameters. In line 4 and 5 of the sample code they use `app.UntitledNotepad` but what if my script saves the file and then the window title is changed. Is there any other way to interact with application windows besides this handle?

```
(1)   >>> from pywinauto import application
(2)   >>> app = application.Application()
(3)   >>> app.start("Notepad.exe")
      <pywinauto.application.Application object at 0x00AE0990>
(4)   >>> app.UntitledNotepad.draw_outline()
(5)   >>> app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Edit -> Replace")
```

In my code I have:

```
app_log = Application(backend="uia").connect(process=appcheck.get_window_pid('Login'), timeout=10)
```

So, even though I can "connect" to this login window I still can't interact with it unless I write `app_log.Login.child_window(`

Answer (score 0):

I assembled some kind of workaround.

```
import re


def get_dlg_string(title):
    windows = Desktop(backend="uia").windows()
    window_list = [w.window_text() for w in windows]
    for window in window_list:
        if re.search(title, window):
            window = window.replace(' ', '')
            window = window.replace(')', '')
            window = window.replace('(', '')
            window = window.replace('-', '')
            window = window.replace(':', '')
            return window
            break


dlg = appcheck.get_dlg_string('Customer Service*')
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title_re='Customer Service*', timeout=10)
cust_searchbox = app[dlg]['SelectDialog']
```

pywinauto dlg syntax seems to not like special characters so I pull a list of all windows, return the first match found (there should only ever be one result in my use case, so the break is just a failsafe) and remove special characters before returning as my dlg variable. To my pleasant surprise you can variablize the child windows when you use the [brackets] formatting as found in the documentation.

https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowTo.html#how-to-specify-a-dialog-of-the-application